# Declaration of a class containing a non-visual component

Tags: delphi, components

I am writing a class that is going to control and handle input and output to a device. Part of the I/O is going to be by serial port, for which I am using the Comport library (Tcomport, Dejan Crnila). The Tcomport and TcomDataPacket components are declared as TComponent decendants.

Is it better to then declare my own class as:

1. A simple class (  TThingy = class)
2. A component (TThingy = class(TComponent)

If 1), what should I pass to the TComPort.create call? At the moment I intend to handle the creation and freeing of the instances manually.

Answer (score 4):

- If you want users to be able to drop one of these components onto a form, or allow ownership to be handled using the `TComponent` mechanism, then derive from `TComponent`.
- Otherwise, derive from `TObject`.

Specifying an `Owner` when you create a `TComponent` framework is optional. If you want to opt out then simply pass `nil` to the constructor of a `TComponent`. When you do that you take on ownership of the component, and it's your job to call `Free` when you are done with it.

So, I suspect that what you wish to do is declare your class like this:

```
type
  TThingy = class
  private
    FComport: TComport;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

....

constructor TThingy.Create;
begin 
  inherited;
  FComport := TComport.Create(nil);
end;

destructor TThingy.Destroy;
begin
  FComport.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: +1. According to the last line in the question, a `TObject` it is.